# Why runOnUiThread in Android is updating more than one views simultaneously

Tags: android

I am trying two different times on two different TextViews. If first button is clicked, then it displays time as desired, but on second button click, the first TextView is updated again with value of second TextView.

```
    private TextView textView1, textView2;
    private Button btn1, btn2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView1 = findViewById(R.id.text_view_1);
        textView2 = findViewById(R.id.text_view_2);
        btn1 = findViewById(R.id.btn_1);
        btn2 = findViewById(R.id.btn_2);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                runTimer(textView1, 0);
            }
        });

        btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                runTimer(textView2, 8);
            }
        });
    }
```

```
int someTime;

    private void runTimer(TextView toolTipTimeText, int time) {
        someTime = time;
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                toolTipTimeText.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        toolTipTimeText.setText(getTime(someTime++));
                    }
                });
            }
        };

        timer.schedule(task, 0, 1000);
    }
```

How can I perform updation of time seperately without affecting the first TextView.